# Uninstall embedded java Mac os

Tags: java, macos

I would like to update Java to Java 7, actually I have a embedded Java in Mac os which I can't  update or uninstall it, I tried to install java 7 instead but when i type `java -version` I get always the old version:

[image]

Please how can I update or remove the installed Java?

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed `JAVA_HOME` in .bash_profile to point to the new Java installation?

Adding `export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"` has done the job for me .

Comment: Yes I added export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home)" to the end of .bash_profile and run it but still showing the old version of java

Comment: Also when I type this in Terminal : `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7` i got this message : Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.7".
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: @nabill. Do you have a Java Preferences app/pane?

Comment: Yes for the new one (1.7)